# If $X$ is a non negative random variable with $E[X]=25$, what can be said about $E[X^3]$, $E[\sqrt{X}]$, $E[\ln X]$, and $E[e^{-X}]$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

How I solve this? (Jensen's inequality?)

Comment: I doubt you can say anything more precise than what Jensen's inequality gives you, unless you have stronger assumptions.

Comment: In some cases you get both an upper and a lower bound by incorporating non-negativity.

Comment: @LucasCastro - If you have a different question, you should make a new question (and show what you tried). Don't edit an existing question into a totally different one.

Comment: Do not deface your question by editing it into something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

**Jensen's inequality**

\begin{align}
f \text{ concave}:& \;\;\; E[f(X)] \leq f(E[X])  \\[2ex]
f \text{ convex}:& \;\;\; E[f(X)] \geq f(E[X]) 
\end{align}

---

Since $f(X)=\sqrt{X}$ and $f(X)=\ln{X}$ are concave, it follows that
\begin{align}
E\left[\sqrt{X}\right] &\leq \sqrt{E[X]} = \sqrt{25}  \\[2ex]
E\left[\ln{X}\right] &\leq \ln E[X] = \ln 25  
\end{align}

---

Since $f(X)=X^3$ and $f(X)=e^{-X}$ are convex, it follows that
\begin{align}
E\left[X^3\right] &\geq E[X]^3 = 25^3  \\[2ex]
E\left[e^{-X}\right] &\geq e^{-E[X]} = e^{-25}  
\end{align}

Comment: But more can be said since $X$ is non-negative: for instance $\mathbb E[e^{-X}] < 1$.

Comment: @ErickWong You are right. This assumption was introduced after I gave my answer though. Since the question has been closed I didn't fix it.